# Weak convergence of probability measures, Borel measurability and separable spaces

Tags: probability, weak-convergence

Most of the following comes from studying the first pages of van der Vaart and Wellner (1996). Let $(\mathbb{D},d)$ be a metric space and let  $\{P_n, \, n\geq 1\}$ and $P$ be Borel probability measures on $(\mathbb{D},\mathscr{D})$, where $\mathscr{D}$ is the Borel $\sigma$-field on $\mathbb{D}$. Then we say that $P_n$ converges weakly to $P$ if and only if

$\int_\mathbb{D} f \, dP_n \to \int_\mathbb{D} f \, dP, \quad$ for all $f \in C_b(\mathbb{D})$.

Equivalenty, letting $X_n$ and $X$ be $\mathbb{D}$-valued random elements with distributions $P_n$ and $P$ respectively, then $X_n$ converges in distribution to $X$ if and only if

$\mathbb{E}f(X_n)\to \mathbb{E}f(X), \quad$ for all $f \in C_b(\mathbb{D})$.

Letting $(\Omega_n, \mathscr{A}_n)$ be the underlying measure spaces on which the maps $X_n$ are defined,  what we are assuming is that $X_n^{-1}(D)\in  \mathscr{A}_n$, for every Borel set $D \in \mathscr{D}$. This required measurability usually holds when $\mathbb{D}$ is a separable metric space (e.g. $\mathbb{R}^k$ or $[0,1]$ endowed with the sup-norm).

Now, one is often interested into the case in which $X_n$ is a random element of

$\bullet$ $(\mathbb{D},d)=(\ell_\infty(\mathcal{F}),\Vert \cdot \Vert_\mathcal{F})$, the space of bounded functions on a given space $\mathscr{F}$ endowed with the sup-norm;

$\bullet$ $(\mathbb{D},d)=(D[0,1],\Vert \cdot \Vert_{\infty})$, the Scohorod space of càdlàg functions on the closed unit interval endowed with the sup-norm.

These spaces are not separable.

Let's consider an example: $\xi_1,...,\xi_n$ are i.i.d. according to the uniform distribution on $[0,1]$ and defined as coordinate projections on the product probability space $([0,1]^n, \mathcal{B}^n, \lambda^n)$ where $\mathcal{B}$ and $\lambda$ denote the Borel $\sigma$-field and the Lebesgue measure on the unit interval. Letting

$X_n=\left(\, n^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^n 1_{[0,t]}(\xi_i) \, \right)_{t \in [0,1]}$,

we have that the inclusion $X_n^{-1}(\mathscr{D}) \subset \mathcal{B}^n$ fails to hold, since the Borel $\sigma$-field induced by the topology of the sup-norm $\mathscr{D}$ is now "too large". Why is it so? Which is the actual link between separability and Borel-measurability? Moreover, the concept of weak convergence as in the first two displays above can not be employed to study the weak limit of $X_n$, beacause of the lack of Borel-measurability. Intuitively, why the classical theory of weak convergence has been constructed relying on this "specific" measurability requirement?

Comment: In order to answer to a part of the question, I report a summary from pp 150-153 in Billingsley (1968). Let for simplicity n=1. Then in the example $X_n(t)=X_1(t)=1_{[0,t]}(\xi_1)$. Denoting by $A_\theta$ a sphere with center $1_{[0,\theta]}$ and radius $1/2$, we have that for any $H\subset [0,1]$, $\cup_{\theta \in H}A_\theta \in \mathscr{D}$, since it is open (observe that the lack of separability does not allow us to express such set as a countable union of spheres). Moreover, observe that $X_1^{-1}(\cup_{\theta \in H}A_\theta)=\{\omega:\xi_1(\omega) \in H\}$, for $any$ $H\subset[0,1]$.

Comment: If $X_1$ was Borel measurable, we would have that $\{\omega: \xi_1(\omega) \in H \} \in \mathscr{B}$, for $any$ $H\subset [0,1]$. This is not possible, since the power set of $[0,1]$ strictly contains $\mathscr{B}$. This explains why $X_1^{-1}(\mathscr{D})\subset\mathscr{B}$ can't be true. Intuitively speaking, without separability of $(\mathbb{D},d)$, the class of open sets is "too reach". If $(\mathbb{D},d)$ is separable, every open set $D$ would be in the form $\cup_{n\geq1}S_i$, where $S_i$ are spheres, and clearly $X_n^{-1}( \cup_{i \geq 1} S_i) = \cup_{i\geq 1} X_n^{-1}(S_i)$.

Comment: Therefore, in the latter case, Borel measurability is guaranteed by measurability of sets in the form $X_n^{-1}(S)$, where $S$ is a sphere in $(\mathbb{D}, d)$.

Comment: Sorry, above I should have said: the cardinality of the power set of $[0,1]$ is larger than the cardinality of $\mathscr{B}$.

Comment: Final remark: in probability we are able to "construct" measures on cylindrical $\sigma$-fields (in Banach spaces, the coarsest $\sigma$-fields s.t. every continuous linear function is measurable). A cylinder set is the natural open set of a product topology (space of marginal distribution) and cylinder set measure (or promeasure, or premeasure, or quasi-measure, or CSM) is a kind of prototype for a measure on an infinite-dimensional vector space. Now, unlike in the finite dimensional case (e.g. $\mathbb{D}=\mathbb{R}^k$) cylindrical and Borel $\sigma$-field do not usually coincide.

Comment: Therefore, while studying convergence of probability measures, as long as we can "bring the problem back" to the case of (at most countable) product spaces, Borel measurability is fine, continuous functions are measurable and we can exploit the usual characterization of weak convergence as in the first two displays above. When dealing with infinite dimensional metric spaces, things become much more delicate, measurability becomes an issue and some slightly different notions of weak convergence need to be taken into account. Is this (even rough) conclusion correct?

Comment: To be more precise on what I do mean by "bring the problem back", consider the example $(\mathbb{D}, d)=(C[0,1], \Vert \cdot \Vert_\infty)$. This space is separable and all the open spheres can be expressed as countable unions of finite sets $\mathscr{H}=\{f \in C[0,1], (f(t_1),...,f(t_d)) \in H\}$, for every $H$ in the Borel $\sigma$-field of $\mathbb{R}^k$ and points $\{t_1,...,t_k \} \subset [0,1]$. By continuity of the coordinate-projection map, we have that every finite set satisfies $\mathscr{H} \in \mathscr{D}$.

Comment: Now, we have that class of finite sets generates the class of open sets, which in turn generates $\mathscr{D}$. In this view, if we are able to prove weak convergence of $P_n$ to, say, $Q$ on finite sets, we would know that there exists a unique probability measure  $P$ on $\mathscr{D}$ which satisfies $Q(\mathscr{H})=P(\mathscr{H})$, for every finite set $\mathscr{H}$. In this example, convergence on finite sets (read "marginal distributions") plus relatively compactness guarantees weak convergence of $P_n$ to $P$.